# ehCache : Delete keys with prefix

Tags: ehcache, ehcache-bigmemory

I have added the following keys in my ehCache.

```
cache.put(new Element("MyKey1", List1));
cache.put(new Element("MyKey2", List1));
cache.put(new Element("MyKey3", List1));
cache.put(new Element("MyKey4", List1));
```

Now I want to remove them all at a time. But I want to do that with the help of key prefix - "MyKey".

**Update:**

I have managed to do that by the following way -

```
public static void clearStartWith(String key){
      Ehcache cache = getCache(AC.CACHE_NAME);
      Query query;
      Results results;
      query = cache.createQuery();
      query.includeKeys();
      query.addCriteria(Query.KEY.ilike(key+"*")).end();
      results = query.execute();
      for (Result result : results.all()) {
          cache.remove(result.getKey());
      } 
}
```

But the problem is persistence strategy - localTempSwap does not support this feature. Again for using 'localRestartable'  I need an enterprise version. So I need to use 'none' persistence strategy.

Comment: Can you clarify what's not working in the OSS version?